# Why Apache isn't using RAM but Showing Error?

Tags: server, apache2, lamp, php-fpm

I am trying to Optimize LAMP stack. Here's the Configuration of Server.

```
CPU:4 vCore
Ram:4096 MB
Storage:90 GB SSD
Bandwidth: 4000 GB
```

When I try to test the server with **800** Con-current visitors, I get these errors.

```
[alert] socket: 1009293056 select timed out: Connection timed out
[alert] socket: 2058381056 select timed out: Connection timed out
[alert] socket: 1439418112 select timed out: Connection timed out
[alert] socket: 768001792 select timed out: Connection timed out
[alert] socket: -2144266496 select timed out: Connection timed out
[alert] socket: 507827968 select timed out: Connection timed out
```

And Here's the Memory usage at the time I get errors...

```
             total       used       free     shared    buffers     cached
Mem:          3953        333       3619         24         13        141
-/+ buffers/cache:        178       3774
Swap:         1023          0       1023
```

I want to know why I am getting these errors if **3300MB** RAM is free.

I'm doing something wrong and I know that. But I don't know where I'm going wrong.